# Reading math eBooks on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ebook, epub

I want to read eBooks on my iPhone 4. Those eBooks are heavy on mathematical formulas and sometimes diagrams. I have some problems though:

- When I convert PDFs and DJVU to ePub format and download the ePub file to iPhone, then I open it with Stanza, mathematical equations do not show correctly.
- When I open PDFs and DJVUs using Stanza *without* converting to  ePub format, the text appears fuzzy and when I zoom in or out I lose the ability to flip through the pages – and I can't change or close the book.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! To help others help you and contribute to the reference of all things Apple this site is meant be, you should always ask a clear cut question (see [ask]). In this case, a question can be inferred (how to best read mathematical eBooks on an iPhone), but it should be stated in the question text.

Comment: Have you tried opening the files in iBooks? iBooks supports both PDF and epub

Answer (score 3):

Regarding pdf, comverting to another format normally makes things worse rather than better.  For reading pdf, best use an app specifically designed for that, like goodreader or adobe reader, instead of an ebook reader like stanza or ibooks.